# FInd the possible number of ways in which the integers can be chosen.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Find the possible number of ways in which five distinct integers $a,b,c,d,e$ can be chosen from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ to satisfy the following condition:

$$
ab^4c^6d^4e=3^5 \times 2^{16} \times 5^4
$$

Comment: Please typeset in *MathJax* as your equation is unintelligible.

Comment: You can find formatting help [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I'm sorry can you please briefly tell me how?

Comment: I just edited your post.  Please check to see that I correctly conveyed your meaning.  To see how I did it, click edit on your post and you can see how I formatted.

Comment: Do you know about primes and their role in the naturals?

Comment: There is no way to choose them since the only way you can get $5^4$ in the prime factorization and since the integers must be distinct you have $b=5$ but since there are only two multiples of $3$ namely $3$ and $6$ the highest power of $3$ you can get is $4<6$.

Comment: This is impossible without $9$ as an option.

Comment: Even if $9$ were allowed it would still be impossible to have $2^{12}$ even if you could repeat $8$

Comment: Please check now I have verified the values from my peer

Answer (score 1):

Due to symmetry, we can interchange $a,e$ and $b,d$.  As such, we will solve in a manner where we assign $a$ before $e$ and $b$ before $d$ and then multiply our number of ways by $4$.

In order to get $5^4$, we have that $b=5$.

In order to get $3^5$, we have either $a=3, d=6$ or $a=6, d=3$.

Suppose $a=3, d=6$.  As such, we need $c^6e=2^{12}$.  This can be done only with $c=4,e=1$

Suppose $a=6, d=3$.  As such we need $c^6e=2^{15}$.  This can be done only with $c=4,e=8$.

As such, there are two methods before multiplying by four, for a total of eight

Comment: Thank you this solution is quite satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

The only number in the list that has $5$ as a factor is $5$ itself.  As a result, to get the $5^4$ on the right hand side, we need $4$ factors of $5$ on the left.  Since $a,b,c,d,e$ are all supposed to be distinct, then $b=5$ is the only way to get the four factors needed.

You can then see that to get factors of $3$ on the right requires selecting either $3$ or $6$ from the list.  Since $b^4$ is taken, you need $6$ factors of $3$ to show up on the left...and it doesn't look like that is possible.

Please check that the formatted equation says what you wanted it to say.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question what are your views on this now?